# No operation which satisfies the runtime constraints found for "context".

Tags: neoscms

Is there any debugging tool to debug in neos.
Because when i try to print output using print_r browser gets crashed and not able to debug at all.

Could you please suggest me?

Comment: You can use <f:debug>{variable}</f:debug> in template - it's more convenient in most cases. To use variable in template, remember to $this->view->assign('variable', $variable) in you action.

Answer (score 0):

Neos's debugging tool is

`\TYPO3\Flow\var_dump($var)`